# Custom shared content between all pages with Xamarin.Forms Pages and MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application with CrossPlatform XamarinForms1.3 and I would use MvvmCross.
With MvvmCross Presenters, I can use XamarinForms pages instead of native views. With [XamarinForms Renderers](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) I can customize each control on each platform.

So I want to make a **custom base view on each platform**. For example, I would like to display same layout between different pages. A further customization of Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage/ContentPage.

For that, for this I have architected my project as well :

```
- Core
    - Pages
        - BasePage (Base UI Page, shared between different pages - it is just simple class)
        - FirstPage : BasePage
        - SecondPage : BasePage
    - ...
- Droid
    - Renderers
        - BasePageRenderer : PageRenderer (UI Page layout on Android)
- Windows Universal App
    - Renderers
        - BasePageRenderer : PageRenderer (UI Page layout on Windows)
```

I know that Xamarin Renderers are: Views for Android, PhoneApplicationPage for Windows Phone, iOS UIView. I would like to customize the Android View, the PhoneApplicationPage and iOS UIView.

On Android, I have find that : [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), I go to follow steps and try to find a solution.

[image: BaseView]

Comment: Possibly, I can turn it into an activity that implements a Drawer or open another activity (but that would actvities 2)

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: I just clarify my question. As such, I want to mix Xamarin Forms, Xamarin Renderers (to custom Xamarin Forms Pages Layout) and MvvmCross Presenters (to use Xamarin Forms Pages)